# How to change the theme and the surroanding area color in Code::Block in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: ide

My default color in CB can hurt my eyes when I code for a long time. So I want to change it into dark color like that.

[image]

Comment: I wasn't thinking about this when you asked me on the other question.  You can mess around with the settings for the colors in *Settings -> Editor -> Syntax Highlighting*  And also see https://medium.com/@yzhong.cs/change-editor-theme-for-code-blocks-windows-linux-mac-92e9c15cbca4